# Calling parse from six in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

It seems the module six [isn't supported for Python2.7](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves.urllib.parse), so if I call a module that imports it like so:

```
from six.moves.urllib import parse
```

Then I get:

```
NameError: global name 'parse' is not defined
```

Does anyone know if there is a Python2.7 module that does the same stuff that can replace this one?

EDIT:

This is the traceback (it's an API scraper that is using the foursquare module, which is where the problem is calling parse...):

```
me@myplace.com [~/scraping/fsquare]# python2.7 fsquare.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fsquare.py", line 24, in <module>
    auth_url = client.oauth.auth_url()
  File "/home/me/scraping/fsquare/foursquare/__init__.py", line 157, in     auth_url
    params=parse.urlencode(params))
NameError: global name 'parse' is not defined
```

Comment: That should work. Where are you running this from?

Comment: Can confirm that the exact code above works for Python 2.7.6 with six 1.10.0.

Comment: Add the traceback. I think there is something else happening that you have not shared in your question

Comment: ["Six supports every Python version since 2.6."](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/1.10.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost certainly have something like the following in your code:

```
def f():
   params = parse.urlencode("...")
f()
from six.moves.urllib import parse
```

You have called a function somewhere before parse has been imported.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare/blob/master/foursquare/__init__.py#L155), the line `params=parse.urlencode(params))` is on *line 155* but the traceback says *line 157* so either you have modified the source or you are using a version that is > 11 months old as that was the last time `foursquare/__init__.py` was updated, most likely you have modified something.

You might want to consider actually installing the package in place of running the code from the same folder:

```
pip2 install foursquare
```

Then run your script from a different directory and that will give you a definitive answer to your issue.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check that.

Comment: @the_t_test_1, why is `foursquare` in the same dierectory as the script you are running, did you actually install the package?

Comment: So.................... I discovered that the module wasn't properly installed (and my web dev insists that six isn't compatible with 2.7 ... sigh, nevermind!)... so I've solved it with workaround of just using the module files. I'm not sure whose answer I can mark correct really. Padraic made the best long-range detective guess and would have been correct had my homework been done properly, so I'll mark that right - don't know if that's against the rules - please don't flame me! :)

Comment: @the_t_test_1, lol, mine is the only answer so you are stuck with mine for now, the package was not actually installed at all, your code only ran at all because you had your script in the same folder as the foursquare source.

Comment: Yep, I was trying to wing it all because my host wouldn't install any of the packages... less said about this attempt the better (I got it all working now) but thanks anyway for the answer anyway!